# cURL fails in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, curl, github-actions

I'm running a Raspberry Pi 4 as a server for a .NET Core side-project of mine. Nothing too fancy or heavy. After trying to get going with a webhook and uploading files with scp to the Pi and failed (still don't know why at this point; scp problem might be the same as cURL problem), I decided to make myself a small API which accepts a file and deploys it to the specified path. The API is working both from inside and outside the Pi as I've tested it using cURL and Postman with a 20MB zip file, but when I run this command from inside a GitHub Action, I get a long waiting time and then a fail message.

Command:

```
curl --request POST --url https://example.com/ --header 'cache-control: no-cache' --form path=DEPLOY_PATH --form archive=@FILE_PATH --form token=TOKEN
```

Output:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
            
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
0 8776k    0     0    0 65536      0  42750  0:03:30  0:00:01  0:03:29 42722
0 8776k    0     0    0 65536      0  25862  0:05:47  0:00:02  0:05:45 25852
0 8776k    0     0    0 65536      0  18533  0:08:04  0:00:03  0:08:01 18528
0 8776k    0     0    0 65536      0  14444  0:10:22  0:00:04  0:10:18 14441
0 8776k    0     0    0 65536      0  11833  0:12:39  0:00:05  0:12:34 13091
0 8776k    0     0    0 65536      0  10022  0:14:56  0:00:06  0:14:50     0
0 8776k    0     0    0 65536      0   8691  0:17:14  0:00:07  0:17:07     0
...
0 8776k    0     0    0 65536      0     63 39:37:37  0:17:11 39:20:26     0
0 8776k    0     0    0 65536      0     63 39:37:37  0:17:11 39:20:26     0
curl: (55) SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 110
##[error]Process completed with exit code 55.
```

With both scp and cURL commands there seems to be a common problem. If I try to send a simple text file or a tar.gz containing a text.file, it works. If I try to do the same with a .dll file or a tar.gz containing a .dll file, it does not. I don't really know if the problem is because of the files or their size. To be noted that the API accepts files as big as 100MB at the moment and I'm only trying to deploy a small package of ~10MB.

Output with -v arg:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying IP...
* TCP_NODELAY set

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to URL (IP) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [112 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [2861 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [300 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [37 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [16 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=URL
*  start date: Sep 18 16:51:41 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Dec 17 16:51:41 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "URL" matched cert's "URL"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
} [5 bytes data]
> POST /api/Deployment/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: URL
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> cache-control: no-cache
> Content-Length: 3333
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------ca1748c91973ca89
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
{ [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
} [5 bytes data]

100  3333    0     0  100  3333      0   2154  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  2153
100  3333    0     0  100  3333      0   1307  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  1307
100  3333    0     0  100  3333      0    938  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--   938
100  3333    0     0  100  3333      0    732  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--   732
100  3333    0     0  100  3333      0    600  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--   614
100  3333    0     0  100  3333      0    508  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--     0
100  3333    0     0  100  3333      0    441  0:00:07  0:00:07 --:--:--     0
...
100  3333    0     0  100  3333      0     57  0:00:58  0:00:57  0:00:01     0
100  3333    0     0  100  3333      0     56  0:00:59  0:00:58  0:00:01     0
100  3333    0     0  100  3333      0     55  0:01:00  0:00:59  0:00:01     0
100  3333    0     0  100  3333      0     54  0:01:01  0:01:00  0:00:01     0* Empty reply from server

100  3333    0     0  100  3333      0     54  0:01:01  0:01:00  0:00:01     0
* Connection #0 to host URL left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
##[error]Process completed with exit code 52.
```

EDIT: Switching to a Windows runner instead of Ubuntu solved the cURL problem, but I'm still open to suggestions regarding this question, as this is merely a workaround rather than a solution.